# How to check if a certain line in a text contains a number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if line 8 in a text file includes the number 1, and if that line does, print a statement. Hours of searching have not given me much help and I do not know how to go about this.

Comment: `if '1' in linecache.getline(thefilename, 8): print (statement)`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, post your code and the results it produces. That will help us to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure hours of searching have not given you any help!

Comment: You probably need to read the python tutorial.

Comment: @Arman holy cow ... thats awesome ... I never knew about linecache ... thanks

Comment: `is_there = '1' in open('myfile').readlines()[7]`

Comment: @Arman Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a slice of the file lines using `islice`. This is efficient and doesn't require reading in the entire file.

Then just take the `next` line:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename) as f:
    line = next(islice(f, 8))
    if '1' in line:
        print 'statement'
```